# Are these two statements equivalent? Which one is true?

Tags: real-analysis

A set $S$ is countable if and only if there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ of real numbers such that $S=\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

vs.

A set $S$ is countable if and only if there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ of real numbers such that for every $x\in S$, there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x = a_n$.

Are these two statements equivalent? Which one is true?

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Would it be nit-picking to point out that neither is true unless we assume $S$ is a set of real numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: We can rewrite the second statement as:

> A set $S$ is countable if and only if there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $S\subseteq\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}.$

From this, we can see that the first version implies the second. To go the other way, we need to find an appropriate *subsequence* $\{a_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that $S=\{a_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\},$ which will be possible if $S$ is infinite, or use the original sequence to define a new sequence $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with only finitely-many distinct terms such that $S=\{c_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. Does that get you started?

Answer (score 0):

These two statements are equivalent because the second statement is merely adding a quantifier and a layer of specificity to the set $S$, while the first statement operates without the added layer.

Comment: I would contend that the first is actually *more* specific. See my answer.